# Ajax request check is not working in AppController Cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

The ajax request not detected in the AppController.

I have printed the params array. Here is the sample.

```
CakeRequest Object
(
    [params] => Array
        (
            [plugin] => 
            [controller] => permissions
            [action] => api_auth
            [named] => Array
                (
                )

            [pass] => Array
                (
                )

            [prefix] => api
            [api] => 1
            [ext] => json
            [_Token] => Array
                (
                    [key] => 00f665112046ea0d5794b5f93b6a035f62a59ada
                    [unlockedFields] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [isAjax] => 
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
        )

    [query] => Array
        (
        )

    [url] => api/permissions/auth.json
    [base] => 
    [webroot] => /
    [here] => /api/permissions/auth.json
    [_detectors:protected] => Array
        (
            [get] => Array
                (
                    [env] => REQUEST_METHOD
                    [value] => GET
                )

            [post] => Array
                (
                    [env] => REQUEST_METHOD
                    [value] => POST
                )

            [put] => Array
                (
                    [env] => REQUEST_METHOD
                    [value] => PUT
                )

            [delete] => Array
                (
                    [env] => REQUEST_METHOD
                    [value] => DELETE
                )

            [head] => Array
                (
                    [env] => REQUEST_METHOD
                    [value] => HEAD
                )

            [options] => Array
                (
                    [env] => REQUEST_METHOD
                    [value] => OPTIONS
                )

            [ssl] => Array
                (
                    [env] => HTTPS
                    [value] => 1
                )

            [ajax] => Array
                (
                    [env] => HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH
                    [value] => XMLHttpRequest
                )

            [flash] => Array
                (
                    [env] => HTTP_USER_AGENT
                    [pattern] => /^(Shockwave|Adobe) Flash/
                )

            [mobile] => Array
                (
                    [env] => HTTP_USER_AGENT
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Android
                            [1] => AvantGo
                            [2] => BlackBerry
                            [3] => DoCoMo
                            [4] => Fennec
                            [5] => iPod
                            [6] => iPhone
                            [7] => iPad
                            [8] => J2ME
                            [9] => MIDP
                            [10] => NetFront
                            [11] => Nokia
                            [12] => Opera Mini
                            [13] => Opera Mobi
                            [14] => PalmOS
                            [15] => PalmSource
                            [16] => portalmmm
                            [17] => Plucker
                            [18] => ReqwirelessWeb
                            [19] => SonyEricsson
                            [20] => Symbian
                            [21] => UP\.Browser
                            [22] => webOS
                            [23] => Windows CE
                            [24] => Windows Phone OS
                            [25] => Xiino
                        )

                )

            [requested] => Array
                (
                    [param] => requested
                    [value] => 1
                )

        )

    [_input:protected] => 
)
```

This is how I have checked the ajax request..

```
if($this->request->is('ajax')){
      //ajax request
} else {
     // not ajax request.
}
```

But always I get false result i.g not ajax request.

I am using the cakephp 2.3 version.

Here is the code sample of the ajax request code.

```
$.ajax({
        url: backendAPI +'/students/profile.json',
        type: 'POST',                     
        data: this.studentdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        context: this
      })
      .done(function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
               if( response.students.status == 'success' ) {
                  self.model.fetch();
                  mStitute.moduleTRANS['LeftSideBarStudent'].fetch();
               } else {
                   if( response.students.message_type == 'single' ) {
                       Core.showAlert(response.students.message.toString(), 'show', response.students.status);
                       Core.hideAlert(10000);
                   } else {
                       var message = "";
                       $.each(response.students.message, function(i, v){
                             message = message + '<br/>' +  v;
                       });
                       Core.showAlert(message, 'show', response.students.status);
                       Core.hideAlert(10000);
                   }
              }
        });
```

Comment: Can you tell *where* in the AppController are you printing the params? And also and example of an ajax request you're doing?

Comment: Yes this params array is printed in the function which going to be call with ajax. The array print I have copied from response of ajax request.

Comment: Can you post js code please?

Comment: I have updated the question with the ajax code.

Comment: Do you have `Router::parseExtensions('json');` enabled?

Comment: Yes. Because if I try it with URL through browser it works.

Comment: Do you have the RequestHandler component enabled?

Comment: Have you added `echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();` at the end of your layout/view?

Comment: well, is `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` set? If you are requesting a .json url - it's not really necessary to test for is ajax - it's a json file. What's the _actual_ problem? There's no CakePHP code in the question.

Comment: It is not a json file. It's cakephp extention which manage all .json, .xml or .yourext etc. I want to know why it's working with the other peoples not for me. Is this fault of the cakephp or any server fault there?

Comment: `It is not a json file.` - that's obvious, otherwise the request wouldn't reach cakephp at all - please answer my previously question (is HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH set) and show a complete code example of "the problem" - there's no error message or indication of what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax request(jquery script) you have added **context: this**.

Can you please try to remove this and then check in backend for the ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$this->RequestHandler->isAjax()` .

If return true your request is ajax. But before add 'RequestHandler' component in your controller.